# Show modal on Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to show a modal with the following code:

```
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';

Vue.use(VModal);
```

On template:

```
<modal name="hello-world">
  hello, world!
</modal>
```

Vue part:

```
myMethod() {
    this.$modal.show('hello-world');
}
```

When trying to call myMethod(), I get the error "Cannot read property 'show' of undefined". Any ideas?

Comment: you need to check `this.$modal` , this object seems not work as expected.where did you register this `vue-js-modal`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in a vue-cli simple environment 
and its works fine, tested

main.js

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import Vue from "vue";
import VModal from "vue-js-modal";

Vue.use(VModal);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Hello world test</h3>
    <modal name="hello-world">
      hello, world!
    </modal>
    <button @click="showModal">show modal</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$modal.show("hello-world");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```